# Как в woocommerce не учитывать определённую категорию при выборе похожих товаров?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Имеется магазин, в котором к каждому товару автоматически приписывается категория "Весь ассортимент" при сохранении. Соответственно в похожих товарах выводится весь ассортимент. Как можно выбросить из учёта эту категорию или хотя бы выводить похожие товары только по меткам, не учитывая категории. Или возможно ещё какое-то решение есть?

Comment: Буквально первый результат по поиску "woocommerce exclude category from related products" Вам даст ответ.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, я искал подобное, и пробовал, но подобные варианты убирают все товары с определённой категорией из списка похожих товаров. То есть все товары пропадают из списка похожих. Нужно не товары с категорией выкинуть из списка, а категорию выкинуть из списка. Спасибо что уделили внимание моему вопросу. И печально что даже не попытались вникнуть в суть.

Comment: "каждому товару автоматически приписывается категория "Весь ассортимент" при сохранении", "выбросить из учёта эту категорию" - читая это, логично предположить, что вы все товары хотите скрыть. Сформулируйте вопрос яснее.

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы при выборке похожих товаров не учитывалась категория "Весь ассортимет".  Пример 2 товара с категориями:
-Весь ассортимент, Угловые диваны
-Весь ассортимент, Модульные диваны
Нужно чтобы не выводились друг у друга в похожих товарах.